# Read UTF-8 special chars from external file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, special-characters, readfile

I have a UTF-8 encoded file "myFile.aaa" with non-printable char represented by hexadecimal x80 (decimal 128).

I need to develop a Javascript function that will read this char from myFile.aaa and return its decimal value, 128.

Is it possible to do that? How?

If I copy myFile.aaa content to "`var data`", and do "`data[0].charCodeAt(0)`" I get value 8364 instead of 128.

Thanks

Comment: A freestanding decimal 128 is not a valid UTF-8 character. Where does it come from?

Comment: If I need to write in a file a byte representing decimal 128, what char encoding should I use, so that I can easily read it from Javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your UTF-8 encoding makes sense, so I'm going to tell you the best way I've found of dealing with dodgy AJAX data. Set the content type as user-defined:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined')
```

You can then just read the file as plain bytes instead of encoded characters.

Comment: I really need to have a byte representing decimal 128 in the file to be read, doesn't matter what encoding I am using (I can change UTF-8 for any other encoding that makes sense for you). Will then your code work the same without any changes on myFile.aaa? Thanks

Comment: I think it should do. You just need to know how many bytes your chars represent.